# Lock picture movement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding some pictures in excel. 
It would be nice to lock the resizing with mouse vertical and horizontal. So it should be just the diagonal movement allowed.

the rotation should also be locked. Is that possible in vba? do you know anything? i was searching a lot, but just find the `.locked` function, that locks my whole picture/shape.

in this picture there are the movements which should be locked/not possible.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can prevent specific methods of resizing

Comment: There is no in-built method. You need to preserve the original position, angle and size and then continuously monitor and reset it whenever needed.

Comment: it's not worth to monitor this, but its a nice idea, thank you

Comment: @Niklas May I ask what the overall purpose of this is? Maybe it is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there is a solution for Y while you asked X.